# Email setup for Django in AWS using SES

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-allauth

I am trying to setup email capability for my Django website on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I have activated Simple Email Service (SES) and verified two email address for testing. Furthermore, I have followed instruction to install and setup [Dango-SES](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses). However, when I try to sign up in my website pretending to be a new user I  receive this error in my browser (Traceback):

```
    Environment:


Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'newsletter',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'ajaxuploader')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session')



Traceback:

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  210.         return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  79.                                             **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  188.                                                           **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/views.py" in post
  102.             response = self.form_valid(form)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/views.py" in form_valid
  231.                 self.get_success_url())

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/utils.py" in complete_signup
  188.                          signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/utils.py" in perform_login
  148.             send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/utils.py" in send_email_confirmation
  319.                                                     signup=signup)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/models.py" in send_confirmation
  60.         confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/models.py" in send
  166.         get_adapter(request).send_confirmation_mail(request, self, signup)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/adapter.py" in send_confirmation_mail
  447.                        ctx)

File "/opt/python/current/app/allauth/account/adapter.py" in send_mail
  140.         msg.send()

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  292.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ses/__init__.py" in send_messages
  200.                                           dkim_headers=self.dkim_headers)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ses/connection.py" in send_raw_email
  323.         return self._make_request('SendRawEmail', params)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ses/connection.py" in _make_request
  119.             self._handle_error(response, body)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ses/connection.py" in _handle_error
  177.         raise ExceptionToRaise(response.status, exc_reason, body)

Exception Type: SESAddressNotVerifiedError at /accounts/signup/
Exception Value: SESAddressNotVerifiedError: 400 Email address is not verified.
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: webmaster@localhost</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>e89fc6ee-07aa-11e8-ad7d-79b7437444ea</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

That is confusing because I am using verified email to sign up (email verified by SES). I am using django-allauth for authentication and registration.
This is my Django setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'My Key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'My Key'

AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

Can anyone give an advice on this?

Thank you very much!

Regards

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: @Alasdair, you mean my full django-setting ?Thank you.

Comment: No, I mean the entire error. You've said the error message is `SESAddressNotVerifiedError`, but the full traceback will show where that error occurred.

Comment: Please show any other `EMAIL` settings, e.g. `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` or `SERVER_EMAIL`.

Comment: @Alasdair - I have edited the post with the full traceback. I did not put any other email setting, I believe. I start to suspect that it is using the Django default email setting instead of the SES verified email. Thank you for your help already!

Answer (score 5):

Your view is trying to send an email, and using the [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#default-from-email) as the from address.

You haven't set `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, so it is defaulting to `webmaster@ localhost`. Amazon SES gives you an error, because you have not verified this address.

You can fix the problem by setting `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` to an address that you have verified with SES.

Comment: Yes - that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help!